# Display the search results like the original pages

Tags: wp-query, customization, search

I'm creating my site (locally) and I'm using the starter theme underscores.me

I created few pages using bold, italic, and other text styles, but I noticed that in the **Search Results** page, the content of the pages is displayed without the text styles.

Look at this image to better understand the problem:

[image]

I'm almost sure that in order to customize the search behaviour I have to edit the file **searchform.php** or **search.php**, but I don't know what I have to write in there.

Could you help?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

Here it is my `search.php` content:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * @package sitename
 */

get_header();
?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php
                    /* translators: %s: search query. */
                    printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'sitename' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' );
                    ?>
                </h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                /**
                 * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                 * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when search results pull a page's content into a section for an excerpt, it runs the content through a filter which runs [`strip_tags`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp) or some equivalent WordPress specific function that removes any and all HTML tags so as to not break the site due to a opening `<div>` tag not having a closing partner because the excerpt cut off the ending before it was properly closed, and would then potentially break the layout of the site, and other reasons, but that's the simplest example.

To customize the behavior, you will probably have to edit search.php or content-search.php (if it exists) to pull in your own version of the content to show, whether it be all the content, or a modified version of the excerpt system.

Comment: Thank you very much, in my `search.php` file there is no `strip tags` function. I edited the question adding the code, do you see?

Comment: Yep, the line `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );` means that it's loading another file '/template-parts/content-search.php' and though that function might not be listed in that file either, that doesn't mean that it's not running on the content or excerpt.  WordPress has a lot of hooks and functions that it runs behind the scenes.